# Tool to explain C statements containing bitwise operators

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I've been reading Kernighan and Ritchie's "The C Programming Language".

I am finding it very hard to get through section **2.9 Bitwise Operators**

Specifically:

> Exercise 2-6 Write a function setbits(x,p,n,y) that returns x with the
>   n bits that begin at position p set to the rightmost n bits of y,
>   leaving the other bits unchanged.

There's answers to exercises [here](http://users.powernet.co.uk/eton/kandr2/krx206.html) from a clever chap called Richard Heathfield.

Richard's answer is:

```
return (x & ((~0 << (p + 1))
           | (~(~0 << (p + 1 - n)))))
     | ((y & ~(~0 << n)) << (p + 1 - n));
```

**Question**

Does anyone know of a tool that will explain lines of code like the one above?

I'm hoping something exists that is similar to the various online regex explainers, but for bitwise operations.

Comment: A tool like people of stack overflow? ;)

Comment: Pencil and paper?

Comment: I don't believe there is a tool that will parse the bit-wise operator expression and explain it to you. You will most likely have to read up on each operator to understand the meaning behind the code. check out the following link http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html and just work through sections at a time and try and explain it to yourself in plain English (or your language of choose) to ensure your understanding

Comment: First thing is to break it onto multiple lines to make it easier to read.  I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: You can break this function down yourself to see what the individual bits are doing. I would separate out the various bits that get ORed together and inspect them until enlightenment.

Comment: The best tool is a coding guideline that frowns upon developers writing code like the above.

Comment: I don't think an explanation in words would be any more understandable than that code itself.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: instead of "frowning upon" you could try to invent a "better" method.

Comment: @wildplasser: My method would be the same mechanism, but with intermediate variables with useful names, such as `bitsAboveP = x & (~0 << (p+1))`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Aw, c'mon Oli, that's C as it was *meant* to be written :-).

Answer (score 2):

Lets make this human readable, shall we?

> let *x*, *y*, *p*, and *n* be input
>   let *temp1*, *temp2*, *temp3*, and *result* be equal to zero
>   let *temp1* be equal to *p* plus 1
>   let *temp1* be equal to the one's complement of 0 shifted left by *temp1*
>   let *temp1* be equal to the bitwise AND of *x* and *temp1*
>   let *temp2* be equal to *p* plus 1 minus *n*
>   let *temp2* be equal to the one's complement of 0 shifted left by *temp2*
>   let *temp2* be equal to the one's complement of *temp2*
>   let *temp1* be equal to the bitwise OR of *temp1* and *temp2*
>   let *temp3* be equal to *p* plus 1 minus *n*
>   let *temp2* be equal to the one's complement of 0 shifted left by *n*
>   let *temp2* be equal to the one's complement of *temp2*
>   let *temp2* be equal to the bitwise AND of *y* and *temp2*
>   let *temp2* be equal to *temp2* shifted left by *temp3*
>   let *result* be equal to the bitwise OR of *temp1* and *temp2*

Source: My Brain.

From this C code (expanded from the OP):

```
int setbits(int x, int p, int n, int y)
{
    int result = 0;

    // evaluate the expression
    {
        int temp1 = 0;
        int temp2 = 0;
        int temp3 = 0;

        temp1 = p + 1;
        temp1 = ~0 << temp1;
        temp1 = x & temp1;

        temp2 = p + 1 - n;
        temp2 = ~0 << temp2;
        temp2 = ~temp2;

        temp1 = temp1 | temp2;

        temp3 = p + 1 - n;

        temp2 = ~0 << n;
        temp2 = ~temp2;
        temp2 = y & temp2;

        temp2 = temp2 << temp3;
        result = temp1 | temp2;
    }

    assert(result == ((x & ((~0 << (p + 1))| (~(~0 << (p + 1 - n))))) | ((y & ~(~0 << n)) << (p + 1 - n))));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth he just asked for it to be explained, he already knew what the code did, This just helps him understand how it works.

Comment: @Jon I hope Richard's code makes this a little easier to digest.  An important lesson here is that you don't earn bonus points for condensing a complex operation into a single line of code.  The original solution you were asking about is far less readable and generally doesn't perform any better with normal compiler settings.